# Segregate dataset based on certain matching variables

Tags: sql, sas

I have 2 datasets , one is base dateset and the other is subset of it , I want to create a dataset where the record is not present in the subset dataset but present in base dataset. So if combination of acct_num test_id trandate actual_amt is not present in the subset  then it should come in the resultant dataset.

```
DATA base;
INPUT acct_num test_id tran_date:anydtdte. actual_amt final_amt final_amt_added ;
format tran_date date9.;
DATALINES; 
55203610 2542 12-jan-20 30 45 45
16124130 8062 .         56 78 78 
16124130 8062 14-dec-19 8  78 78
80479512 2062 19-mar-19 32 32 32
70321918 2062 20-dec-19 1  93 54
17312410 6712 .         45 90 90
17312410 6712 15-jun-18 0  90 90
74623123 2092 17-aug-18 34 87 87
24245321 2082 22-jan-17 22 56 67
;
run;

data subset;
input acct_num test_id tran_date:anydtdte. actual_amt final_amt final_amt_added ;
format tran_date date9.;
DATALINES; 
55203610 2542 12-jan-20 30 45 45
16124130 8062 .         56 78 78 
16124130 8062 14-dec-19 8  78 78
17312410 6712 .         45 90 90
74623123 2092 17-aug-18 34 87 87
24245321 2082 22-jan-17 22 56 67
;
run;
```

data that I want

```
80479512 2062 19-mar-19 32 32 32
70321918 2062 20-dec-19 1  93 54
17312410 6712 15-jun-18 0  90 90
```

I have tried using not in function in SQL but it does not match multiple variable in that statement.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please properly format your data to make it consumable, as it stands it's a mess and unusable.

Comment: i have the data thats sensitive and cannot be shared , thats just a example , and i just want to know the logic to be used

Answer (score 0):

It is about how to solve minus set, see [Except operator](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/except.php#:~:text=SQL%20Server%3A%20EXCEPT%20Operator%201%20Description.%20The%20SQL,...%206%20Example%20-%20Using%20ORDER%20BY.%20)

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table want as 
  select * from base
  except 
  select * from subset
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of all the observed values in subset, then simply merge the base file with the combinations found in subset and output the records that are in base only.

Note it is important to restrict subset_combinations to non-duplicates and only keep the sorting variables, else you may overwrite the values from subset.

```
proc sort data=base; 
  by acct_num test_id tran_date actual_amt;
proc sort data=subset out=subset_combinations (keep=acct_num test_id tran_date actual_amt) nodupkey; 
  by acct_num test_id tran_date actual_amt;

data want;
  merge base (in=in1) subset_combinations (in=in2);
  by acct_num test_id tran_date actual_amt;
  if in1 & ^in2;
run;
```